# Updating model data in the meilisearch index when editing this model's links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

Input data regarding the database:

- The product table has 4 million positions;
- Adjacent tables, which will be relations for the product model, have an average of 1 to 4 million records respectively, which will total 10-15 million records additionally, in addition to those 4 million records in the product table.

Let's take as an example the relationship of a product with categories, which can be many:

```
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Next, in the `makeAllSearchableUsing()` method, we define with which links we want to store the **product model** in the **meilisearch** index

```
protected function makeAllSearchableUsing($query): Builder
{
    return $query->with(['categories']);
}
```

After we load the data into the index of the meilisearch system, with further search, we will be given something like this answer (only the part necessary for the demonstration is left):

```
{
  id: 12615,
  name: "FORD chip...",
  slug: "...",
  categories: [
    {
      id: 41735,
      product_id: 12615
      name: "Ford...",
    },
    {
      id: 41739,
      product_id: 12615
      name: "Ford Alternate...",
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the product categories (and, accordingly, all other links that we will store with it) are hardcoded into its data array.

**The question is:**

When updating the name of a category, I **need to write the logic for updating product data myself, and in general any other models that have a relationship with categories and it is written in meilisearch** (for example, in events, or in an observer), or **this is possible in automatic mode**, with some **more advanced settings** of this package ?

Thanks if anyone can help.

It's not just an inconvenience, but also the fact that if I change the name of a category, for example, I will have to pre-record several million products that have it listed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [`events`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events) or trait with auto model events like saving or updated like [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/model-updating-event-not-called) ?